# Name of tabs (in Chrome)

Tags: discussion

I have recently posted two different questions, both with the tag "reference-request". Today I noticed that in the tabs of Chrome they are marked differently. The first tab reads `reference request - Title of the Question`, while on the second one it is written `Title of the Question - reference request`. Why is that?

Comment: I blame the dark wizards.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a screenshot?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> The most popular tag in the question is added to the HTML title, **if it isn't found** in the actual question title.

From [When are tags included in the HTML title of the question page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220932/251274)

Since you used the word "reference" in your question [Reference for LPV controls](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/687470/127096), the system decided it would be redundant  to include the tag "reference-request".

SE takes SEO seriously. But if you wish, you can [Remove the most popular tag from the title using JavaScript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71951/251274).

Comment: Great, thank you very much!